# It is ok to use ContentResolver in SQLiteOpenHelper?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

During `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate`, I need to add various rows to the database.  In order to not have redundant code, I would like to call wrapper functions that use `ContentResolver` - that is, the functions that the app-level code uses.

However, doing this would mean the `ContentProvider` would be calling `getContentResolver` and, ultimately, generating a recursive call to itself.  Is this ok?  Will I run into problems in some environments?  Is there a better way to do this?

I realize this is not the most efficient way to do this, but database creation should seldom happen.  My larger concern is to avoid redundant code - having two functions with the same `ContentValues`.put calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peri,

What do you mean by not having redundant code. You should be able to utilize SqLiteOpenHelper for what you want and not have to use a content resolver. Let me know what you're trying to do and I can share some code. I use SqLiteOpenHelper extensively on projects.

Comment: Sure, if I don't use a ContentResolver, it's easy.  Perhaps I don't need one.  I'm trying to be prepared for allowing the database to be persistent regardless of what I may do to the app in the future.  More specifically, I need to do a bunch of inserts.  The code for the inserts exists in a wrapper, using a ContentResolver.  But, from SQLiteOpenHelper, how can I get to that insert code?

Comment: Better yet, ultimately, I'd like the Activity to detect whether the database exists and, ultimately, allow the user to connect to an existing databsae (in the cloud) or create one locally.  (This is a ways off, though.)

Comment: Well, I refactored the code so I could share it on "both sides of the fence".  Not quite as clean as I'd like, but at least nothing is redundant.